# "Java.io.FileNotFoundException" Error after getting React native build apk

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, filenotfoundexception

I made a photo sharing application. I used this package "https://github.com/react-native-share/react-native-share". Photos are in "android / app / src / main / assets / img". Everything was working. I've done every step here "https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android" there is no problem. Then I tested apk with this command "npx react-native run-android --variant = release". But share method was not working. I viewed the error with the "adb logcat" command. Everything was working before I got the apk. I don't understand the problem. Thanks for your answers.

**Share method**

```
const myCustomShare = async (image) => {

    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        const imgURI = Image.resolveAssetSource(image).uri;
        let p1 = await ImgToBase64.getBase64String(imgURI);

        const shareOptions = {
          url: `data:image/png;base64,${p1}`,
        };

        const ShareImage = await Share.open(shareOptions);
      } else {
        console.log('Camera permission denied');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error => ', error);
    }
  };
```

**adb logcat output**

```
System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: android_app_src_main_assets_img_img1
02-24 15:31:55.410  5559  5605 W System.err:    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1444)
02-24 15:31:55.410  5559  5605 W System.err:    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1295)
02-24 15:31:55.410  5559  5605 W System.err:    at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1015)
02-24 15:31:55.410  5559  5605 W System.err:    at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.getBitmap(MediaStore.java:886)
02-24 15:31:55.410  5559  5605 W System.err:    at fr.snapp.imagebase64.RNImgToBase64Module.getBase64String(RNImgToBase64Module.java:42)
02-24 15:31:55.410  5559  5605 W System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-24 15:31:55.410  5559  5605 W System.err:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
02-24 15:31:55.410  5559  5605 W System.err:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151)
02-24 15:31:55.410  5559  5605 W System.err:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
02-24 15:31:55.410  5559  5605 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
02-24 15:31:55.410  5559  5605 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-24 15:31:55.410  5559  5605 W System.err:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
02-24 15:31:55.411  5559  5605 W System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
02-24 15:31:55.411  5559  5605 W System.err:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
02-24 15:31:55.411  5559  5605 W System.err:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
02-24 15:31:55.417  5559  5604 I ReactNativeJS: 'Error => ', [Error: Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: android_app_src_main_assets_img_img1]
```

Comment: `Photos are in "android / app / src / main / assets / img"` Thast will be a path on your development machine. And not even a full path.

Comment: And... which statement causes the exception? And which file is not found? You did not tell.

Comment: @blackapps is correct. Most likely `ImgToBase64` can't find the specified file. If you are not using the react-native in a hybrid environment, images should be in your js bundle, not in android subfolders.

Comment: @blackapps, @UğurEren thanks for answering. I changed the images folder location. Photos in assets/img folder in root directory are now. Nothing has changed. The file content I bring the images `{
    id: 1,
    image: require('../img/img1.png'),
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    image: require('../img/img2.png'),
  },....etc` . I still keep getting the same error.For example, when I want to share a photo named img2, I get the following error "Error => ', [Error: Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: assets_img_img23]"

Comment: `const imgURI = Image.resolveAssetSource(image).uri;` What is image? You are not showing what you do. We do not even see an image file name. Adapt your code.